# T-SQL function for data scrambling

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, obfuscation, data-masking, scramble

**GOAL:** I have to obfuscate sensible data on a SQL Server database. [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15)  is not an option. Data shuffle is not an option. The only option is Data Scramble.

**SOLUTION:** In the most hidden meander of the internet I found a [very nice piece of code](http://techbrat.blogspot.com/2012/12/scrambled.html) that can easily adapt to most of the data type:

```
-------------------------------------------------

--A view to give you Random Values
CREATE VIEW dbo.random(value) AS SELECT RAND();

GO
-------------------------------------------------

--Randomization Procedure
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRandomizedText (
@OldValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN

  DECLARE @NewValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @nCount AS INT
  DECLARE @cCurrent AS CHAR(1)
  DECLARE @cScrambled AS CHAR(1)
  DECLARE @Random AS REAL
 
  SET @NewValue = ''
  SET @nCount = 0
   WHILE (@nCount <= LEN(@OldValue))
  BEGIN
    SELECT @Random = value FROM random
    SET @cCurrent = SUBSTRING(@OldValue, @nCount, 1)
     IF ASCII(@cCurrent) BETWEEN ASCII('a') AND ASCII('z')
       SET @cScrambled = CHAR(ROUND(((ASCII('z') - ASCII('a') - 1) * @Random + ASCII('a')), 0))
    ELSE IF ASCII(@cCurrent) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z')
       SET @cScrambled = CHAR(ROUND(((ASCII('Z') - ASCII('A') - 1) * @Random + ASCII('A')), 0))
    ELSE IF ASCII(@cCurrent) BETWEEN ASCII('0') AND ASCII('9')
       SET @cScrambled = CHAR(ROUND(((ASCII('9') - ASCII('0') - 1) * @Random + ASCII('0')), 0))
    ELSE
       SET @cScrambled = @cCurrent

    SET @NewValue = @NewValue + @cScrambled
    SET @nCount = @nCount + 1

  END
   RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@NewValue))
END
GO 
-------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks to this function every name or surname can be scrambled this way:

```
SELECT
[FirstName],
UserName = dbo.fnRandomizedText([FirstName])
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
```

| FirstName | UserName |
| --- | --- |
| Ken | Tkm |
| Terri | Pggkg |
| Roberto | Thewgnu |
| Rob | Trs |
| Gail | Dgbp |

And with the same function I can scramble e-mail addresses:

```
SELECT 
[EmailAddress]
,email = dbo.fnRandomizedText([EmailAddress])
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[EmailAddress]
```

| EmailAddress | email |
| --- | --- |
| a0@adventure-works.com | w6@dgdfrrsay-clqdw.lcw |
| a1@adventure-works.com | t5@ckqnqpepv-qyfen.xgm |
| aaron0@adventure-works.com | npnlv3@eeihbcfpq-kfxca.qki |
| aaron1@adventure-works.com | jpmco2@emswfuhkl-ertts.cmt |
| aaron10@adventure-works.com | ebbfq42@njckrkprq-ecqbr.ayy |

This is an amazing piece of code and I would like to add the option to scramble dates.

Is there a way to scramble in the same way dates this way:

| Dates | New_Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 11/09/2003 | 12/01/1995 |
| 12/12/2021 | 13/02/1956 |
| 30/05/1998 | 23/03/1988 |
| 14/01/1984 | 01/02/1980 |

That might not be easy because the DataType for dates is much more complex. And I cannot tell how I can approach this problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: FYI, that function is going to perform terribly. It's a multi-line scalar function (which can perform poorly anyway) with  `WHILE` (which *will* be awfully slow). If you're on SQL Server 2019 you could make use of inlining, however, you may well be better off for an iTVF. As for scrambling the dates, do you need to? You could easily end up with bad data. For example, what if you end up with changing someone's DOB to a date that is makes them too young, or makes it so that something happened before something else did, but said chain of events are impossible.

Comment: Dates are not stored as a string, they are a *date*, an integer value of time elasped since an epoch, there is nothing to "scramble" - you are just after creating a random date it seems.

Comment: `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`. As to what you'd consider acceptable "scrambling", that's up to you -- I doubt you'd be OK with (say) generating a date in the year 1857 or 2312. On the other hand, if all *other* data is scrambled there's less incentive to twiddle the date as well, or to do it with anything more complicated than "all dates are now 2011-12-13". There is a careful line to thread between making the data unreadable, and making it unusable (for example, the scrambled e-mail addresses you show, with invalid TLDs, would certainly cause trouble in some systems).

Comment: Also fwiw that "amazing" function is far from amazing imho - it's 10 years old and could be implemented far better and without the need for any looping.

Comment: @Larnu, you are right, scrambling data this way will make the database inconsistent. `FirstName` and `LastName` will never be the same in other tables. DOB will be anything from the middle age to Space Odyssey... I tried, unsuccessfully, to push for Dynamic Data Masking but The Manager said he wasn't feeling comfortable (he didn't understand how it worked). Especially in this project we need consistency with Name, Surname, DOB but I would like to keep going and when  The Manager will realize it doesn't work we will go for Dynamic Data Masking

Comment: Perhaps, rather than reinventing the wheel, you'd be better off with a anonymisation tool, such as Redgate's [Data Masker](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/data-masker/) (I do not work for Redgate, nor have any affiliation with them). Though many of them are not particularly cheap.

Comment: @Stu, completely agree with you. An alternative would be Data Shuffle that mix up and down data on the same column. The DB will be inconsistent anyway but at least the data look more realistic. But anyway this is a POC that will show to The Manager how useless this approach is. Is sad that I have to arrive to this point. I took this post as a lesson for me to learn new things about functions and scrambling data datatype. Of course the code is old but I find the approach fascinating. It tries to be one-size-fits-it-all

Comment: @Larnu Red-Gate Data Masker is awesome but is >$8000 per Tb. The alternative ApexSQL Mask is cheaper, I tried it, it's buggy as hell. We are poor, we deserve poor code quality :)

Comment: I did say that the [good] solution's aren't cheap, @FrancescoMantovani . ;)

Comment: fwiw the company I work for had very similar requirements (like most do at some point) and we looked at various off the shelf solutions; in the end we rolled our own process to obfuscate personal data when we had to move production data to UAT or training systems, nothng else was able to meet the business requirements or keep up with the changes required.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @JeroenMostert. In defense of this function I have to say that the TLDs looks pretty realistic to me. Maybe tomorrow a new TLDs record like `.hgm` can be introduced, who knows... and `wgcmjmwcs-swfqo.hwl` can be a domain

Comment: Interesting @Stu, I have to move this database to UAT too. In your case were you able to change FirstName, LastName, etc... all over the database and keep the database consistency? What was your solution?

Comment: More complexity than can fit in a sentence! iirc it modifed base data eg a customer name and the same data was populated elsewhere it was used, dates eg DOB are not changed - once you've obfuscated a name/address etc then a DOB or transaction date etc is meaningless - you could generate a random date and potentially end up with the same date, so it's of no concern, for our use case.